# Saving arrayList instead of overriding of each item click in Navigation Drawer?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, arraylist, navigation-drawer

I've got a Navigation drawer with list of items like `Home`, `News`, `Photos`. When I click an item, the corresponding fragment is loaded and shown.

Suppose if I click `News`, it performs Async Task and saves the data in `ArrayList`. My problem is, if I hit `News` item again in Navigation drawer, it deletes the old `ArrayList` values and shows the new items (i.e overriding).

Since I'm new to fragment, I couldn't figure out how to save my old ArrayList values.

MainActivity.java

```
DemoFragment fragment = new DemoFragment();
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
```

DemoFragment.java

```
public class DemoFragment extends Fragment {
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    ArrayList<Post> postArrayList;
    PostRecyclerAdapter postRecyclerAdapter;
    ProgressWheel progressWheel;   

    public DemoFragment() {

        // Required empty public constructor       
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);   
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment    
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_post, container, false);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.posts_list);
        // progressBar = (ProgressBar)v.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        progressWheel = (ProgressWheel) v.findViewById(R.id.progress_wheel);

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        // use a linear layout manager
        LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);


        new LoadPosts(getActivity(), progressWheel, recyclerView).execute();
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        setRetainInstance(true);


    }

}
```

LoadPosts.java

```
class LoadPosts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    List<ParseObject> parseObjects;
    Context context;
    FragmentManager supportFragmentManager;
    ArrayList<Post> postArrayList;
    String postC, postT,postI;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    ProgressWheel progressWheel;


    public LoadPosts(FragmentActivity context, ProgressWheel progressWheel, RecyclerView recyclerView) {

        this.context = context;
        this.progressWheel = progressWheel;
        this.recyclerView = recyclerView;

    }


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        //progressDialog.show();
        progressWheel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... avoid) {

            postArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
            // dont care about postC, postT. I get these values from parse db
            Post post = new Post();
            post.setContent(postC);
            post.setCreatedAt(postT);
            postArrayList.add(post);


        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

        progressWheel.setVisibility(View.GONE);   
        PostRecyclerAdapter postRecyclerAdapter = new PostRecyclerAdapter(context, postArrayList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(postRecyclerAdapter);

       supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
    }

}
```

Comment: You can simple maintain a int that represents the current open fragment, so if you have loaded the fragment News (position 1), when you click again on News the first code line can be `if(currentPosition != newPosition)loadNewFragment();`

Comment: you can use database to cache old item if needed , or if you want to cache item fragment state just add every instance of fragment in Array list , and check if items.get(position) is existed and not equal null , so use it else use new one ..

Comment: No even if i click News after navigation other item count, it should show the old ArrayList values if there's a problem in fetching the new data when i click `News`. The problem is I'm setting `CustomAdapter` in `onPostExecute()` on `LoadPosts` class.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return your data `postArrayList` back to the caller, coming from `onCreateView`. Remember that when you call `ASyncTask`, a UI thread is created/used, afterwards all the data is released from memory (at some point in time).

Change FROM:

```
public LoadPosts(FragmentActivity context, ProgressWheel progressWheel, RecyclerView recyclerView)
```

TO (as an example, change the third parameter):

```
public LoadPosts(FragmentActivity context, ProgressWheel progressWheel, ArrayList<Post> postArrayList)
```

And in the AsyncTask, change FROM:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
```

TO:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Post> postArrayList) {
   super.onPostExecute(postArrayList);

   return postArrayList;
...
}
```

Notes:

- Basically the idea is to return the modified data back to your Fragment class. I actually never had to do this. I think ASyncTask is built for doing stuff in the background, and then forget about the result.
- The Google webpage says

> onPostExecute(Result), invoked on the UI thread after the background
>   computation finishes.

, link @ [ASyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). Search text for it.

Try it out, keep us posted...

Answer (score 0):

You could maintain a static singleton class with the these arraylist variables and methods to set, get and update your arraylist.

Also, you could setup an Application class and set these variables and method here. The application class is like an unofficial singleton in android development and can be accessed throughout your code.

A singleton class can be any public class with static methods to retrieve, set and update values.

If you want to go the application class way, check out the Application class documentation:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html

Once you've created your Application class, declare your arraylist variables and set getters and setters.